# Resample Weekly into Daily CSV DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database that releases weekly data on Friday afternoons, for data ending on the previous Tuesday.  I am trying to `re-sample` that data into `daily up to yesterdays date`.

I keep running the code below, but it is not resampling into daily business days:

```
df=pd.concat([specl,specs,comml,comms,smalll,smalls], join='inner', axis=1)
df.resample('B').ffill()
```

Comment: You'll likely get better answers if you add a small sample of your input data in your question. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget the sum() method with resample?

```
df=pd.concat([specl,specs,comml,comms,smalll,smalls], join='inner', axis=1)
df = df.resample('B').sum().ffill()
```

Comment: Did you try df = df.resample('B').sum().ffill()

Comment: I tried this but now i get daily with a string of zeros in the fill dates..i changed it to mean, and it works...my only issue is the data stops on 11/6, not thru 11/9...